# Area of a surface of revolution

Tags: calculus

how are you? :)

So, I'm having some trouble trying to solve this:

Find the area of the surface obtained by rotating this about the y-axis

$ y= {x^4\over 4}+  {1\over 8x^2} $ , $ 1 \le x \le 2 $

Thank you!

Ps: sorry for my poor English!

Comment: You want to use that $1+(y^{\prime})^2=1+(x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^{-3})^2=(x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^{-3})^2$

Answer (score 0):

Surface area in this case is given by

$$2 \pi \int_1^2 dx \, x \, \sqrt{1+y'^2}$$

$$y=\frac14 x^4 + \frac18 x^{-2} \implies y'=x^3-\frac14 x^{-3}$$

so that

$$y'^2 = x^6 - \frac12 + \frac{1}{16} x^{-6} \implies 1+y'^2 = x^6 + \frac12 + \frac{1}{16} x^{-6} = \left ( x^3+\frac14 x^{-3} \right)^2$$

Thus, the surface area is

$$2 \pi \int_1^2 dx \, x \left( x^3+\frac14 x^{-3} \right)$$

Can you take it from here?